# Dictionary of German place-names

Tags: etymology, dictionary, place-name

The [*Dictionary of British Place Names*](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199609086.001.0001/acref-9780199609086) explains the origins of the names of towns in the British Isles. Is there a comparable dictionary for place-names in Germany (or in the entire German-speaking world)?

Comment: Google books offers *Die deutschen Ortsnamen* from 1863 and there seems to exists a similar work  from Prof. Helbook (1935) with some 70 pages.

Comment: Not exactly what you’re looking for, but still interesting: [CiNaViz](http://www.thomas-zastrow.de:2001/CityViz/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [chirlu](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2813/chirlu)’s answer telling me that *Ortsnamenbuch* is the German name for this type of dictionary, I found the [*Deutsches Ortsnamenbuch*](http://www.degruyter.com/viewbooktoc/product/175390) (also available [on Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=olXnBQAAQBAJ)). It might not be as thorough as the individual regional ones, but the information I was looking for was there.

Answer (score 5):

There is no “global” dictionary for the German-speaking area. Instead, there are lots of regional projects that often cover individual districts (*Landkreis*). A common term for such a dictionary is *Ortsnamenbuch*.

As an example, there is the [Westfälisches Ortsnamenbuch](https://www.uni-goettingen.de/en/westf%C3%A4lisches-ortsnamenbuch/109675.html), planned to comprise 19 volumes, of which 8 volumes have been published as of March 2016. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a complete list of similar dictionary projects; only a few of them are [listed in the Wikipedia article *Ortsnamenbuch*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortsnamenbuch#Liste_von_Ortsnamenb.C3.BCchern).